# Displaying array items, checking for duplicates and deletion of items in array

Tags: javascript

This program is to add and removing items from an array. It previously did until I tried to add error checking. Currently neither button works correctly.

The Add Button is to check for duplicate entries. If an entry is a duplicate an alert should display. This currently keeps displaying the alert "Duplicate Entry".

The Remove Button is to first check to see if the entry is in the list if not display the alert. If entry is in the list ask the user to confirm deletion of the record. This currently keeps displaying the alert "Item not in list".

Lastly, if possible how do I make every item in the array appear on a new line?

Code:

```js
var groceryList = [];

var groceryitem = document.getElementById('Text1').value;
var description = document.getElementById("groceryinfo");

function Add() {
  if (groceryitem != groceryList.includes(groceryitem)) {

    groceryList.push(groceryitem);

    description.innerText = groceryList.toString();
  } else {
    alert("Duplicate Entry");
  }
}

function Remove() {
  if (groceryList.includes(groceryitem)) {

    if (confirm("Do you want to delete item")) {
      for (var i = 0; i <= groceryList.length; i++) {

        if (groceryList[i] == groceryitem) {
          groceryList.splice(i, 1);
        }
        description.innerText = groceryList.toString();
      }
    } else {
      description.innerText = groceryList.toString();
    }
  } else {
    alert("Item not in list");

    description.innerText = groceryList.toString();
  }
}
```

```html
My grocery list
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="groceryinfo"></div>
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Add this item" onclick="Add()"/>
<input id="Text1" type="text"/>
<br/>
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Remove this item" onclick="Remove()"/>
```

Comment: Why don't you add a remove button (i.e. X) beside each item of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed some issues here and there.
Some notes:

1. You need to read what `groceryitem` is everytime you call `Add()` or `Remove()`, otherwise if you read it the first time it will be `""` and never updated again.
2. To display the items, you can't do `groceryList.toString()` but `groceryList.join(",")`.
   If you want them to be on more lines, you can use `description.innerHTML = groceryList.join("<br/>");`
3. There's no need to compare your item with the list on `groceryitem != groceryList.includes(groceryitem)`. All you need to know is if `!groceryList.includes(groceryitem)` your item is not in the list.

```js
var groceryList = [];
var description;
description = document.getElementById("groceryinfo");

function Add() {
  var groceryitem = document.getElementById('Text1').value;
  if (!groceryList.includes(groceryitem)) {
    groceryList.push(groceryitem);
    document.getElementById('Text1').value = "";
    description.innerHTML = groceryList.join("<br/>");
  } else
    alert("Duplicate Entry");
}

function Remove() {
  var groceryitem = document.getElementById('Text1').value;
  if (groceryList.includes(groceryitem)) {

    if (confirm("Do you want to delete item")) {
      for (var i = 0; i <= groceryList.length; i++) {
        if (groceryList[i] == groceryitem) groceryList.splice(i, 1);
        description.innerText = groceryList.toString();
      }
    } else
      description.innerText = groceryList.toString();
  } else {
    alert("Item not in list");
    description.innerText = groceryList.toString();
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
  My grocery list
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="groceryinfo"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Add this item" onclick="Add()" /><input id="Text1" type="text" />
  <br>
  <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Remove this item" onclick="Remove()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you have some problems in your code, for example:

- you are getting only the first time the `groceryitem`, it should be inside the scope of the funtions in order to get the value each time that you run your function. same applies for removal.
- you are doing a bad comparison in `groceryitem != groceryList.includes(groceryitem)`, mostly because `includes` returns a boolean and you are comparing it to an string/undefined.
- the removal function is good, but it can be improved using `filter`
  like this:

```
if (confirm("Do you want to delete item")) {
   groceryList = groceryList.filter(gi => gi !== groceryitem);
   description.innerText = groceryList.toString();
}
```

below you can find a snipet with your code fully working.

```js
var groceryList = [];
var groceryitem;
var description;
description = document.getElementById("groceryinfo");


function Add() {
  groceryitem = document.getElementById('Text1').value;
  if (!groceryList.includes(groceryitem)) {

    groceryList.push(groceryitem);
    description.innerText = groceryList.toString();
  } else
    alert("Duplicate Entry");
}

function Remove() {
  groceryitem = document.getElementById('Text1').value;
  if (groceryList.includes(groceryitem)) {

    if (confirm("Do you want to delete item")) {
      groceryList = groceryList.filter(gi => gi !== groceryitem);
      description.innerText = groceryList.toString();
    }
  } else {
    alert("Item not in list");
    description.innerText = groceryList.toString();
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
  My grocery list
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="groceryinfo"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Add this item" onclick="Add()" /><input id="Text1" type="text" />
  <br>
  <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Remove this item" onclick="Remove()" />
  <script>
  </script>
```